# Create data class that is Parcelable

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I am developing Android project in Kotlin. I want to create a model class that implements Parcelable interface. This is what I tried:

```
@Parcelize
data class School(
    @Expose val name: String?,
    @Expose val address: String?,
): Parcelable
```

But I get compiler error saying that "Class School is not abstract and does not implement abstract memeber `public abstract fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel!, p1: Int):Unit` defined in `android.os.Parcelable`".

I understand what the error is saying. But how to get rid of this error?  My Kotlin version is 1.3.50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

to your Android block within your app build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

**check you have Added this**

```
 androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

and try to implement Parcelable like this

```
class School(var name:String, var address:String):Parcelable
```

pass data like this

```
 val school = School("demo","demo")
        val intent = Intent(this, activityB::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("schooldata",school)
        startActivity(intent)
```

get like this

```
 var school = intent.extras.getParcelable<School>("schooldata")
    schooldata.setText("${school.name}"+"\n"+"${school.address}")
```